# Setting Lifespan of Two Factor Token In ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am calling the method, GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync() from UserManager in ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2 to generate Two Factor Tokens and would like to know if there is way to set the expiry of the token. The default seems to be around 8 minutes. I do know how to set the expiry for email confirmation and password reset tokens using DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions but not for Two Factor Tokens.

thanks for any help!!